# QPS/Call quota limit?

Tags: asana

I keep getting:

Response:
{"errors":[{"message":"You have made too many requests recently. Please, be chill."}]}

When trying to download all my tasks - is there a published QPS or other quota limit so I know how liong I should pause between requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

As stated in the [documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#Errors), the current request limit is around 100 / minute. The error response you are getting back also contains a `Retry-After` header which contains the number of seconds you must wait until you can make a request again.

We may also be institute a daily limit at some point in the future -- we think 100 / minute is a reasonable burst rate, but not a reasonable sustained rate throughout the day. However, we are not enforcing a daily limit yet.